# Non-tedious AST transformation proofs in Agda

Tags: agda

I'm at the ["simple imperative programs"](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/Imp.html) chapter in Software Foundations, doing exercises with Agda too along the way. The book notes that doing proofs on AST-s is tedious and proceeds to present automation tools in Coq.

How can I reduce the tedium in Agda?

Here's an example code:

```
open import Data.Nat hiding (_≤?_)
open import Function
open import Data.Bool
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Data.Empty
open import Data.Product
open import Data.Unit hiding (_≤?_)

data AExp : Set where
  ANum : ℕ → AExp
  APlus AMinus AMult : AExp → AExp → AExp

aeval : AExp → ℕ
aeval (ANum x) = x
aeval (APlus a b) = aeval a + aeval b 
aeval (AMinus a b) = aeval a ∸ aeval b  
aeval (AMult a b) = aeval a * aeval b

opt-0+ : AExp → AExp
opt-0+ (ANum x) = ANum x
opt-0+ (APlus (ANum 0) b) = b
opt-0+ (APlus a b) = APlus (opt-0+ a) (opt-0+ b)
opt-0+ (AMinus a b) = AMinus (opt-0+ a) (opt-0+ b)
opt-0+ (AMult a b) = AMult (opt-0+ a) (opt-0+ b)

opt-0+-sound : ∀ e → aeval (opt-0+ e) ≡ aeval e
opt-0+-sound (ANum x) = refl
opt-0+-sound (APlus (ANum zero) b) rewrite opt-0+-sound b = refl
opt-0+-sound (APlus (ANum (suc x)) b) rewrite opt-0+-sound b = refl
opt-0+-sound (APlus (APlus a a₁) b) rewrite opt-0+-sound (APlus a a₁) | opt-0+-sound b = refl
opt-0+-sound (APlus (AMinus a a₁) b) rewrite opt-0+-sound (AMinus a a₁) | opt-0+-sound b = refl
opt-0+-sound (APlus (AMult a a₁) b) rewrite opt-0+-sound (AMult a a₁) | opt-0+-sound b = refl
opt-0+-sound (AMinus a b) rewrite opt-0+-sound a | opt-0+-sound b = refl
opt-0+-sound (AMult a b) rewrite opt-0+-sound a | opt-0+-sound b = refl
```

Some specific problems here:

First, were I to write a non-verified program in plain Haskell, I would factor out term recursion or use generic programming. I can write a generic transform function in Agda too:

```
transform : (AExp → AExp) → AExp → AExp
transform f (ANum x)     = f (ANum x)
transform f (APlus a b)  = f (APlus  (transform f a) (transform f b))
transform f (AMinus a b) = f (AMinus (transform f a) (transform f b))
transform f (AMult a b)  = f (AMult  (transform f a) (transform f b))

opt-0+ : AExp → AExp
opt-0+ = transform (λ {(APlus (ANum 0) b) → b; x → x})
```

But then the proofs become horrible. I also tried to define a standard catamorphism, and then define both evaluation and transformation in terms of that, and then tried to prove things in terms of the functions (corresponding to constructors) that are arguments to the catamorphism, but I pretty much failed with that approach. So, here I'd  like to know if there is a feasible "generic" approach to proof writing, which focuses only on the relevant cases and skips over others.

Second, Agda doesn't take into account "catch all" patterns when unfolding function definitions. Recall this part from my proof:

```
opt-0+-sound (APlus (ANum zero) b) rewrite opt-0+-sound b = refl
opt-0+-sound (APlus (ANum (suc x)) b) rewrite opt-0+-sound b = refl
opt-0+-sound (APlus (APlus a a₁) b) rewrite opt-0+-sound (APlus a a₁) | opt-0+-sound b = refl
opt-0+-sound (APlus (AMinus a a₁) b) rewrite opt-0+-sound (AMinus a a₁) | opt-0+-sound b = refl
opt-0+-sound (APlus (AMult a a₁) b) rewrite opt-0+-sound (AMult a a₁) | opt-0+-sound b = refl
```

In all the cases below the first line, Agda doesn't remember that we've already covered the only relevant case to `opt-0+` and thus we have to write out every constructor again. This issue grows markedly more irksome as the number of constructors increases. 
Is there a trick to eliminate the boilerplate cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's generalize your `transform` a little:

```
foldAExp : {A : Set} -> (ℕ -> A) -> (_ _ _ : A -> A -> A) -> AExp -> A
foldAExp f0 f1 f2 f3 (ANum x)     = f0 x
foldAExp f0 f1 f2 f3 (APlus a b)  = f1 (foldAExp f0 f1 f2 f3 a) (foldAExp f0 f1 f2 f3 b)
foldAExp f0 f1 f2 f3 (AMinus a b) = f2 (foldAExp f0 f1 f2 f3 a) (foldAExp f0 f1 f2 f3 b)
foldAExp f0 f1 f2 f3 (AMult a b)  = f3 (foldAExp f0 f1 f2 f3 a) (foldAExp f0 f1 f2 f3 b)
```

Now we can write this function:

```
generalize : ∀ f0 f1 f2 f3
           -> (∀ x   -> aeval (f0 x)   ≡ aeval (ANum x))
           -> (∀ a b -> aeval (f1 a b) ≡ aeval (APlus a b))
           -> (∀ a b -> aeval (f2 a b) ≡ aeval (AMinus a b))
           -> (∀ a b -> aeval (f3 a b) ≡ aeval (AMult a b))
           -> (∀ e -> aeval (foldAExp f0 f1 f2 f3 e) ≡ aeval e)
generalize f0 f1 f2 f3 p0 p1 p2 p3 (ANum x) = p0 x
generalize f0 f1 f2 f3 p0 p1 p2 p3 (APlus a b)
  rewrite p1 (foldAExp f0 f1 f2 f3 a) (foldAExp f0 f1 f2 f3 b)
  | generalize f0 f1 f2 f3 p0 p1 p2 p3 a | generalize f0 f1 f2 f3 p0 p1 p2 p3 b = refl
generalize f0 f1 f2 f3 p0 p1 p2 p3 (AMinus a b)
  rewrite p2 (foldAExp f0 f1 f2 f3 a) (foldAExp f0 f1 f2 f3 b)
  | generalize f0 f1 f2 f3 p0 p1 p2 p3 a | generalize f0 f1 f2 f3 p0 p1 p2 p3 b = refl
generalize f0 f1 f2 f3 p0 p1 p2 p3 (AMult a b)
  rewrite p3 (foldAExp f0 f1 f2 f3 a) (foldAExp f0 f1 f2 f3 b)
  | generalize f0 f1 f2 f3 p0 p1 p2 p3 a | generalize f0 f1 f2 f3 p0 p1 p2 p3 b = refl
```

So if we have such functions `f0`, `f1`, `f2` and `f3`, that don't change the "meaning" of any appropriate subexpression (`Num _` for `f0`, `APlus _ _` for `f1` and so on), than we can fold any expression with these functions without changing its "meaning". Here is a trivial example:

```
idAExp : AExp → AExp
idAExp = foldAExp ANum APlus AMinus AMult

idAExp-sound : ∀ e → aeval (idAExp e) ≡ aeval e
idAExp-sound = generalize _ _ _ _ (λ _ → refl) (λ _ _ → refl) (λ _ _ → refl) (λ _ _ → refl)
```

Now we need decidable equality machinery for "remembering" covered cases. I'll post a link to the whole code below, since there is a lot of boilerplate. And here is the lemma, you want to prove:

```
0+-f1 : AExp -> AExp -> AExp
0+-f1 a         b with a ≟AExp ANum 0
0+-f1 .(ANum 0) b | yes refl = b
0+-f1  a        b | no  p    = APlus a b

opt-0+ : AExp → AExp
opt-0+ = foldAExp ANum 0+-f1 AMinus AMult

0+-p1 : ∀ a b -> aeval (0+-f1 a b) ≡ aeval (APlus a b)
0+-p1  a        b with a ≟AExp ANum 0
0+-p1 .(ANum 0) b | yes refl = refl
0+-p1  a        b | no  p    = refl

opt-0+-sound : ∀ e → aeval (opt-0+ e) ≡ aeval e
opt-0+-sound = generalize _ _ _ _ (λ _ → refl) 0+-p1 (λ _ _ → refl) (λ _ _ → refl)
```

Let's prove more fancy lemma.

```
fancy-lem : ∀ a1 a2 b1 b2 -> a1 * b1 + a1 * b2 + a2 * b1 + a2 *  b2 ≡ (a1 + a2) * (b1 + b2)
fancy-lem = solve
  4
  (λ a1 a2 b1 b2 → a1 :* b1 :+ a1 :* b2 :+ a2 :* b1 :+ a2 :* b2 := (a1 :+ a2) :* (b1 :+ b2))
  refl
    where
      import Data.Nat.Properties
      open Data.Nat.Properties.SemiringSolver
```

Now we want to make such optimization on an `AExp` term:

```
left : AExp -> AExp
left (ANum   x  ) = ANum x
left (APlus  a b) = a
left (AMinus a b) = a
left (AMult  a b) = a

right : AExp -> AExp
right (ANum x    ) = ANum x
right (APlus a b ) = b
right (AMinus a b) = b
right (AMult  a b) = b

fancy-f3 : AExp -> AExp -> AExp
fancy-f3 a b with left a | right a | left b | right b
fancy-f3 a b | a1 | a2 | b1 | b2 with a ≟AExp APlus a1 a2 | b ≟AExp APlus b1 b2
fancy-f3 .(APlus a1 a2) .(APlus b1 b2) | a1 | a2 | b1 | b2 | yes refl | yes refl =
  APlus (APlus (APlus (AMult a1 b1) (AMult a1 b2)) (AMult a2 b1)) (AMult a2 b2)
fancy-f3  a              b             | a1 | a2 | b1 | b2 | _        | _        = AMult a 

opt-fancy : AExp → AExp
opt-fancy = foldAExp ANum APlus AMinus fancy-f3
```

And the soundness proof:

```
fancy-p3 : ∀ a b -> aeval (fancy-f3 a b) ≡ aeval (AMult a b)
fancy-p3 a b with left a | right a | left b | right b
fancy-p3 a b | a1 | a2 | b1 | b2 with a ≟AExp APlus a1 a2 | b ≟AExp APlus b1 b2
fancy-p3 .(APlus a1 a2) .(APlus b1 b2) | a1 | a2 | b1 | b2 | yes refl | yes refl =
  fancy-lem (aeval a1) (aeval a2) (aeval b1) (aeval b2)
fancy-p3 .(APlus a1 a2)  b             | a1 | a2 | b1 | b2 | yes refl | no  _    = refl
fancy-p3  a             .(APlus b1 b2) | a1 | a2 | b1 | b2 | no  _    | yes refl = refl
fancy-p3  a              b             | a1 | a2 | b1 | b2 | no  _    | no  _    = refl

opt-fancy-sound : ∀ e → aeval (opt-fancy e) ≡ aeval e
opt-fancy-sound = generalize _ _ _ _ (λ _ → refl) (λ _ _ → refl) (λ _ _ → refl) fancy-p3
```

Here is the whole code: http://lpaste.net/106481
It's possible to reduce amount of boilerplate in `generalize` and `≟AExp`. The trick is described here: http://rubrication.blogspot.ru/2012/03/decidable-equality-in-agda.html
Sorry, if something is shown silly, my browser became crazy.

**EDIT:**

There was no need in messy `foldAExp` stuff. Usual `transform` makes things much easier. Here are some definitions:

```
transform : (AExp → AExp) → AExp → AExp
transform f (ANum x)     = f (ANum x)
transform f (APlus a b)  = f (APlus  (transform f a) (transform f b))
transform f (AMinus a b) = f (AMinus (transform f a) (transform f b))
transform f (AMult a b)  = f (AMult  (transform f a) (transform f b))

generalize : ∀ f -> (∀ e -> aeval (f e) ≡ aeval e)
           -> (∀ e -> aeval (transform f e) ≡ aeval e)
generalize f p (ANum x)    = p (ANum x)
generalize f p (APlus a b)  rewrite p (APlus  (transform f a) (transform f b))
  | generalize f p a | generalize f p b = refl
generalize f p (AMinus a b) rewrite p (AMinus (transform f a) (transform f b))
  | generalize f p a | generalize f p b = refl
generalize f p (AMult a b)  rewrite p (AMult  (transform f a) (transform f b))
  | generalize f p a | generalize f p b = refl

idAExp : AExp → AExp
idAExp = transform id

idAExp-sound : ∀ e → aeval (idAExp e) ≡ aeval e
idAExp-sound = generalize _ (λ _ → refl)
```

And the whole code: http://lpaste.net/106500

Comment: Thanks, this is great stuff to ponder.

Comment: I removed some messy stuff, see **EDIT**.

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't need proofs for `no` cases, it's probably better to switch to this datatype:

```
data Dec' {p} (P : Set p) : Set p where
  yes : (p : P) → Dec' P
  no  : Dec' P
```

Because there are `n * (n - 1)` `no` cases and `n` `yes` cases. So this representation is pretty scalable.

It's also possible to make all this decidability work automatically.
Here is the main function for transforming:

```
vecApply : {α γ : Level} {X : Set α} {Z : Set γ} -> (n : ℕ) -> nary n X Z -> Vec X n -> Z
vecApply  0      x  _       = x
vecApply (suc n) f (x ∷ xs) = vecApply n (f x) xs

replace' : (n : ℕ) -> nary n AExp (AExp × AExp) -> AExp -> AExp
replace' n f e with getSubterms n f e
replace' n f e | nothing = e
replace' n f e | just xs with vecApply n f xs
replace' n f e | just xs |  e' , e'' with e ≟AExp e'
replace' n f e | just xs | .e  , e'' | yes refl = e''
replace' n f e | just xs |  e' , e'' | no       = e
```

So you supply some function, that receives `n` arguments and returns two expressions. For example:

```
_==_ : {α β : Level} {A : Set α} {B : Set β} -> A -> B -> A × B
_==_ = _,_

0+-func : AExp -> AExp × AExp
0+-func = λ a2 -> APlus (ANum 0) a2 == a2
```

The first expression is what you want to find and the second expression is for replacing the first. First of all you need to write a function, that finds all appropriate subexpressions. For example

```
ex1-func : (_ _ : AExp) -> AExp × AExp
ex1-func = λ a1 b1 -> AMult (APlus a1 b1) (APlus a1 b1) == ANum 0
```

For `ex1-func` and this term

```
let    a1 = ANum 0
in let b1 = ANum 1
in AMult (APlus a1 b1) (APlus a1 b1)
```

this function should return `ANum 0 ∷ ANum 1 ∷ []` in exactly this order.
To achieve this first you need to determine all "holes" in some expression (`a1` and `b1` in the example above). Then you need to remove duplicates (there are two "holes" for `a1`, while `ex1-func` (and any other function) receives only one `a1` for both holes).

Here is a dirty solution:

```
enlarge : AExp -> AExp
enlarge a = APlus a a

size : AExp -> ℕ
size (APlus a _) = 1 + size a
size  _          = 0

small big : AExp
small = ANum 0
big   = enlarge small

transT : Set
transT = AExp -> AExp

transTs : Set
transTs = L.List transT

left : transT
left (ANum   x  ) = ANum x
left (APlus  a b) = a
left (AMinus a b) = a
left (AMult  a b) = a

right : transT
right (ANum   x  ) = ANum x
right (APlus  a b) = b
right (AMinus a b) = b
right (AMult  a b) = b

directions : AExp -> AExp -> transTs
directions (ANum   _)     (ANum   _)     = L.[]
directions (APlus  a1 a2) (APlus  b1 b2) =
  L.map (λ f -> f ∘ left) (directions a1 b1) L.++ L.map (λ f -> f ∘ right) (directions a2 b2)
directions (AMinus a1 a2) (AMinus b1 b2) =
  L.map (λ f -> f ∘ left) (directions a1 b1) L.++ L.map (λ f -> f ∘ right) (directions a2 b2)
directions (AMult  a1 a2) (AMult  b1 b2) =
  L.map (λ f -> f ∘ left) (directions a1 b1) L.++ L.map (λ f -> f ∘ right) (directions a2 b2)
directions  _              _             = id L.∷ L.[]

add : {l : ℕ} -> ℕ -> transT -> Vec transTs l -> Vec transTs l  
add  _      d  []      = []
add  0      d (x ∷ xs) = (d L.∷ x) ∷ xs
add (suc n) d (x ∷ xs) = x ∷ add n d xs

naryApply : {α γ : Level} {X : Set α} {Z : Set γ} -> (n : ℕ) -> nary n X Z -> X -> Z
naryApply  0      x _ = x
naryApply (suc n) f x = naryApply n (f x) x

naryApplyWith : {α γ : Level} {X : Set α} {Z : Set γ}
              -> (n : ℕ) -> nary n X Z -> (X -> X) -> X -> Z
naryApplyWith  0      x _ _ = x
naryApplyWith (suc n) f g x = naryApplyWith n (f x) g (g x)

directionses : (n : ℕ) -> nary n AExp (AExp × AExp) -> Vec transTs n
directionses n f = L.foldr (λ f -> add (size (f e)) f) (replicate L.[]) $
  directions (proj₁ $ naryApply n f big) (proj₁ $ naryApply n f small) where
    e = proj₁ $ naryApplyWith n f enlarge small

open RawMonad {{...}}

getSubterms : (n : ℕ) -> nary n AExp (AExp × AExp) -> AExp -> Maybe (Vec AExp n)
getSubterms n f e = (λ _ -> map (λ fs -> lhead id fs e) dss) <$> flip (mapM M.monad) dss
  (L.sequence M.monad ∘ neighbWith (λ f g -> dec'ToMaybe⊤ $ f e ≟AExp g e)) where
    dss = directionses n f
```

The idea is to apply your function to two different terms and then find a difference. "Difference" here is a list of functions like `left ∘ right ∘ right` (which is rather dirty, but I suppose could be improved). Now you can navigate. Then you apply this function again, but every term now is bigger than previous, so it's possible to distinguish them (that's what the `size` function does). Finally, this function checks, if all identic holes are filled by identic expressions. And if so, it chooses random (actually, first) expression among every "family of identicals" and collects them into a vector.

Other stuff in the `replace'` function is pretty simple. Transforming function is applied to a vector of subexpressions and the final term is compared with the original. If they are identic, then you found a subexpression, that can be transformed as a transforming function says.

Now you need to move from one subterm to all subterms:

```
replace : (n : ℕ) -> nary n AExp (AExp × AExp) -> AExp -> AExp 
replace n f = transform (replace' n f)
```

That's all for transforming. Proving stuff is pretty symmetric.

```
sound' : ∀ n f
       -> soundnessProof n f
       -> ∀ e -> aeval (replace' n f e) ≡ aeval e
sound' n f p e with getSubterms n f e
sound' n f p e | nothing = refl
sound' n f p e | just xs with vecApply n f xs | vecApplyProof p xs
sound' n f p e | just xs |  e' , e'' | p' with e ≟AExp e'
sound' n f p e | just xs | .e  , e'' | p' | yes refl = p'
sound' n f p e | just xs |  e' , e'' | p' | no       = refl
```

The only difference — `sound'` receives a soundness proof for your transforming function.

```
soundnessProof : (n : ℕ) -> nary n AExp (AExp × AExp) -> Set 
soundnessProof  0      (e' , e'') = aeval e'' ≡ aeval e'
soundnessProof (suc n)     f      = ∀ x -> soundnessProof n (f x)
```

This says, that for all arguments `f` must return a tuple of two terms with identic "meaning". Recall this example:

```
_==_ : {α β : Level} {A : Set α} {B : Set β} -> A -> B -> A × B
_==_ = _,_

0+-func : AExp -> AExp × AExp
0+-func = λ a2 -> APlus (ANum 0) a2 == a2
```

`vecApplyProof` is symmetric at the value level, but a little more complicated at the type level:

```
vecApplyProof : {n : ℕ} {f : nary n AExp (AExp × AExp)}
               -> soundnessProof n f -> (xs : Vec AExp n)
               -> uncurry (λ p1 p2 -> aeval p2 ≡ aeval p1) $ vecApply n f xs
vecApplyProof {0}     p  _       = p
vecApplyProof {suc n} p (x ∷ xs) = vecApplyProof {n} (p x) xs
```

And you also need to move from one subexpression to all subexpressions:

```
generalize : ∀ f -> (∀ e -> aeval (f e) ≡ aeval e)
           -> (∀ e -> aeval (transform f e) ≡ aeval e)
generalize f p (ANum x)    = p (ANum x)
generalize f p (APlus a b)  rewrite p (APlus  (transform f a) (transform f b))
  | generalize f p a | generalize f p b = refl
generalize f p (AMinus a b) rewrite p (AMinus (transform f a) (transform f b))
  | generalize f p a | generalize f p b = refl
generalize f p (AMult a b)  rewrite p (AMult  (transform f a) (transform f b))
  | generalize f p a | generalize f p b = refl

sound : (n : ℕ) -> (f : nary n AExp (AExp × AExp))
      -> soundnessProof n f
      -> (∀ e -> aeval (replace n f e) ≡ aeval e)
sound n f p = generalize _ (sound' n f p)
```

And the final example:

```
fancy-func : (_ _ _ _ : AExp) -> AExp × AExp
fancy-func = λ a1 a2 b1 b2 -> AMult (APlus a1 a2) (APlus b1 b2) ==
  APlus (APlus (APlus (AMult a1 b1) (AMult a1 b2)) (AMult a2 b1)) (AMult a2 b2)

opt-fancy : AExp → AExp
opt-fancy = replace 4 fancy-func

test-opt-fancy :
  let    a1 = ANum 0
  in let a2 = AMinus a1 a1
  in let b1 = ANum 1
  in let b2 = AMinus b1 b1
  in opt-fancy (AMinus (AMult (APlus a1 a2) (APlus b1 b2)) (ANum 0)) ≡
    (AMinus (APlus (APlus (APlus (AMult a1 b1) (AMult a1 b2)) (AMult a2 b1)) (AMult a2 b2)) (ANum 0)) 
test-opt-fancy = refl

fancy-lem : ∀ a1 a2 b1 b2 -> a1 * b1 + a1 * b2 + a2 * b1 + a2 *  b2 ≡ (a1 + a2) * (b1 + b2)
fancy-lem = solve
  4
  (λ a1 a2 b1 b2 → a1 :* b1 :+ a1 :* b2 :+ a2 :* b1 :+ a2 :* b2 := (a1 :+ a2) :* (b1 :+ b2))
  refl
    where
      import Data.Nat.Properties
      open Data.Nat.Properties.SemiringSolver

opt-fancy-sound : ∀ e → aeval (opt-fancy e) ≡ aeval e
opt-fancy-sound = sound 4 fancy-func
  (λ a1 a2 b1 b2 -> fancy-lem (aeval a1) (aeval a2) (aeval b1) (aeval b2))
```

The whole story: http://lpaste.net/106670

**EDIT:** There was wrong composition strategy in the `directions` function (`_∘_ left` instead of `λ f -> f ∘ left`, for example). Fixed now.